# Create executable from a kivy file

Tags: python, kivy, exe

I'm trying to create an exec file from Kivy app(in python) through PyInstaller and I have python classes which I created that importing them gives an error: 'module' has no attribute 'A'(A is a python class which also have a kivy file).
How I can import them through the spec file like importing python modules through 'hidden imports'(I have a problem with importing python modules and importing them through 'hidden imports solved the problem)?

Comment: If you have a statement importing class A, then it is not a hidden import. You may need to specifically include your kv files in the spec file under `datas`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to do that but this is not the problem. I put attention that when I remove the imports to the python modules that I created, it works correctly. So I think they have to be included somehow in the spec file but I don't know how and where.

Comment: You will have to post your code and spec file to get any better answers.